# I keep getting Error when sending AT commands using a USB modem on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, serial-port, at-command, stty

I've a USB modem and a GSM card plugged in, hoping to communicate with it. I installed minicom and atinout, and used this command in minicom:

```
AT+CUSD=1,"*137#",15 
ERROR
```

and on atinout also I did :

```
$ atinout - /dev/ttyUSB3 - < <(echo "AT+CUSD=1,\"*137#\",15")
ERROR
```

notes:

- using modem manager GUI the USSD commands and AT are running well
- and on atinout it used to work few days ago and then it refused working
  hardware version :

  Manufacturer: TCT Mobile International Limited
  `Model: HSPA Data Card`
  `Revision: IX1B5400XX`

Comment: Please copy & paste output instead of posting screenshots

Comment: `EOF` is indeed not a command. Why do you think you can run it as one?

Comment: anyhow, this isn't a question about Linux, or even about the generic AT command set, but about whether a specific device supports a specific extension to that command set -- and yet you haven't even named the hardware.

Comment: ...and as Andrea says, screenshots are not welcome here except when there's no other way to accurately represent content. They aren't searchable, they aren't accessible to folks with disabilities, &c.

Comment: ok I edited the question to fit what is requested here hopefully

Comment: the output was Error , I mentioned the hardware version above and I don't think it's about the hardware , because the same code worked just two days ago and now it is giving me error .

Comment: the question is not about linux but the website didn't allow me to tag minicom and atinout as my reputation is not big enough to do so

Comment: Ahh -- that it works from the GUI is critical information (not present in your original question)! I'd suggest using strace or sysdig to figure out exactly what that GUI is doing differently.

Answer (score 2):

If a device works in some terminal emulators but not others, then the terminal is probably set up incorrectly ("Incorrectly" meaning "different from how the device on the other side of the connection is configured"; there is no right or wrong.)

Usually the problem is one of baud rate, local echo, or LF vs CRLF line endings. You can configure how linux handles a tty device with `stty` (or `setserial`).

Example:

Here I use `atinout` to talk to a Telit DE910 "AUX" port via a UART.

```
$ echo 'AT+CREG?' | atinout - /dev/ttyO1 -
AT+CREG?
+CREG: 1,1

OK
```

So far so good. But this modem has supports multiple physical interfaces for each logical interface, and with my device logical port "AUX" is also available via `/dev/ttyUSB2`. In general I like to use `/dev/ttyUSBn` because [at least some of the ridiculous number of options that can be set by `stty` are fixed](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stty). But in this case the defaults aren't good enough for `atinout` even though we are issuing the same commmand to the same logical port:

```
$ echo 'AT+CREG?' | atinout - /dev/ttyUSB2 -
AT+CREG?


+CREG: 1,1



OK

AT+CREG


ERROR

^C
```

The extra CRLFs are the give-away in this case, and configuring the terminal with `stty raw` fixes it. (In my case `-icrnl` was the only part of `raw` actually needed.)

```
$ stty -F /dev/ttyUSB2 raw
$ echo 'AT+CREG?' | atinout - /dev/ttyUSB2 -
AT+CREG?
+CREG: 1,1

OK
```

The problem with using `stty` is you've changed the device for everybody else. You can use stty to save the initial configuration so that you can restore it when you are done.

```
$ OLDSETTINGS=$(stty -g -F /dev/ttyUSB2)
$ stty -F /dev/ttyUSB2 -igncr -icrnl -ixon -ixoff 
$ stty -F /dev/ttyUSB2 "$OLDSETTINGS"
```

Finally I recommending using `timeout` with `atinout` to avoid a hang when the modem doesn't respond the way `atinout` is expecting.

```
$ echo 'AT+CREG?' | timeout -t5 atinout - /dev/ttyUSB2 -
```